# Way to disable the Visual Studio Code editor title bar

Tags: visual-studio-code

When not using tabs in Visual Studio Code, it still shows a bar with the name of the currently open file.

Editor title bar
[image]

Is there a way to disable this bar completely?

Answer (score 144, accepted):

You can use this setting to hide the title bar: `"window.titleBarStyle": "custom"`. It can be accessed via menu *File* → *Preferences* → *Settings* → *Window* → *Title Bar Style* and set it to custom.

Comment: There are 34 matches for "Window" (version 1.47.3). *"Title Bar Style"* is 2/3 down (scrolling required).

Comment: The awesome customization features of vscode once again to the rescue.

Comment: As of today, this does not _hide_ the title bar, but actually set it to a _custom_ style, which looks sort of windowsy (VSCodium v1.56.2 on Manjaro Gnome)

Comment: This is a life-saver tip. My VS-Code is no longer an ugly creeep

Comment: This does not work as of now, at least for Linux Mint. It just changes the style.

Comment: I am afraid this isn't working on VsCode 1.57.1 (Big Sur)

Comment: @mcnesium You are right. That's why it is called "Custom title bar". May be VS code will try to use the GTK CSD title bar much like how Chrome does.

Comment: Did not hide the titlebar for me, sadly.

Answer (score 4):

Install the [custom CSS extension](https://github.com/be5invis/vscode-custom-css).

Now in your custom stylesheet:

```css
.container > .title {
  display: none !important;
}
```

After, run the command "Enable custom css / js" (and restart).

Comment: Where should i put the css file and how do i use it? Can you please elaborate?

Comment: You can put the css file anywhere on your system. There is a setting from the plugin that let you specify a path to that css file.

Comment: The `.title.tabs` selector worked for me for getting rid of the tab bar. But this still doesn't save any space: the editor windows moves up and leaves an empty space at the bottom of the window.

Comment: `.container > .title` didn't have any effect on my VS Code, even though other styles (like .title.tabs that @Max mentioned) did work.

Answer (score 4):

I tried all the aforementioned tips, without success in hiding the window titlebar.

However, I did find a solution, here: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/174903#issuecomment-1762118744

(and the reply from ryanberckmans above in that thread)

It involves using the apc customize++ plugin to vs code and adding settings to control it, to your user settings.json.

The thread has atleast two different settings proposals, for me, the one I linked to worked (he links to his settings file at the end of his reply).

So:

1. Install vs code [extension Apc Customize UI++](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=drcika.apc-extension)
2. Add this to your user settings.json file:

```js
  // ================================================================================
  // APC - UI Customizer
  // ================================================================================
  "window.titleBarStyle": "native",
  "apc.menubar.compact": true,
  "apc.electron": {
    "frame": false,
    "titleBarStyle": "hidden"
  },
  "apc.header": {
    "height": 37
  },
  "apc.sidebar.titlebar": {
    "height": 37
  },
  "apc.activityBar": {
    "size": 40,
    "itemSize": 40,
    "itemMargin": 0
  },
  "apc.stylesheet": {
    ".title-label": "display: none !important",
    ".composite.title": "display: block !important",
    ".monaco-workbench .part.sidebar .title-actions .actions-container": "justify-content: space-evenly !important"
  }
```

I also have tabs and menubar hidden. This poses a problem, because I cannot invoke the menubar at all (i e, alt-f does not work). So, that is a consideration, you are limited to ctrl-shift-p.

Hope this helps someone!
BR! /mawi

Answer (score 3):

I faced this issue today, so according to the screenshot you attached it looks like file path is showing with a title bar. So to hide this completely, you can remove this property called "workbench.editor.showTabs" if it's value is false from settings.json file situated in /Users/(user_name)/Library/Application Support/Code/User/settings.json

Comment: yep! `workbench.editor.showTabs` is the right key to set. This should be the accepted answer

Answer (score 3):

I played around with suggested options from VSCode and found this to work

make sure that you have your `Window Title Bar Style` set to `custom`
open the `settings.json` file located in `/Users/{your-username}/Library/Applcation\ Support/Code/User/settings.json`

Append the following to the JSON object

```
"editor.titleBar.enabled": false
```

Another option could be to try setting this option in the settings file

```
  "workbench.colorCustomizations": {
    "titleBar.forground": "#00000000",
    "titleBar.activeForeground": "#00000000",
    "titleBar.background": "#00000000",
    "titleBar.activeBackground": "#00000000",
    ...
```

This is my machine settings

[image]
[image]

here's a comprehensive list of options you can use to tweak the current the or even your own theme. no additional 3rd party extensions are needed, just tine in the saddle!

happy coding =)

Answer (score -3):

File → Preferences → Settings → Window → Title Bar Style
Now choose custom title bar.

Comment: There are other answers (and a accepted one) that provide the OP's question, and they were posted some time ago. When posting an answer [see: How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), please make sure you add either a new solution, or a substantially better explanation, especially when answering older questions.