# Vscode issues in VMware

Tags: ubuntu, visual-studio-code, vmware, vmware-workstation

I'm running on Windows and have a VM with Ubuntu. I recently upgraded my Ubuntu to version 23.04, and now I'm experiencing strange behavior in VSCode. The issue is that when I maximize the window, I am unable to interact with the bottom part of VSCode. This means I can't click on the terminal or other tabs located in that area, nor perform any other actions in that half of the window. Sometimes, if I have another application open behind VSCode, clicking on the bottom part of the VSCode window takes me to the other application instead.

I have tried various troubleshooting steps, such as disabling all extensions, reinstalling VSCode, and updating everything, but none of these have resolved the issue.

Interestingly, I created a new virtual machine (VM) with a fresh installation of Ubuntu 22, and everything seems to be working fine there. This leads me to suspect that the problem may be related to VMWare and its compatibility with the new version of Ubuntu.

Has anyone else encountered a similar issue or found a solution?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Way to disable the Visual Studio Code editor title bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47255696/way-to-disable-the-visual-studio-code-editor-title-bar)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was having the same issue with Visual Studio Code.

The way I fixed it was to set "Title Bar Style" from `native` to `custom`, as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47255696)

You can simply search for the term in the settings menu, and it will come up.

Comment: Can confirm that doing this solved my issue. Thank you for helping out. What a weird error though.