# VSCode Hide Menu Bar completely

Tags: visual-studio-code, settings, customization

Is there a way to completely get rid of / hide the menu bar in VSCode?

[VSCode Menu Bar visible](https://i.stack.imgur.com/479qO.png)

What I've seen everywhere was the option to use the command palette and search for "View: Toggle menu bar visibility".
[VSCode Menu Bar visible](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xjyKe.png)
It's not what I wanted to achieve, but instead I'm looking for a way to just completely get rid of it as for me it doesn't have any purpose and just takes up some space.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Way to disable the Visual Studio Code editor title bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47255696/way-to-disable-the-visual-studio-code-editor-title-bar)

Comment: @starball I use Windows10, this didn't seem to work for me