Can I change the color of or hide the title bar of Visual Studio Code on Ubuntu?

I want to disable the title bar showing "Welcome - Desktop ...". Full Screen isn't an option.
Is there an option to make it black or just disable it all?
This is Ubuntu 22.04

check the operating system settings, there should be an apearance setting that specifies the theme color, as well as a dark mode ...

similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47255696/way-to-disable-the-visual-studio-code-editor-title-bar
